# How to authenticate facebook user with username and password from an external website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

I am new to web development. My goal is:
- I have username and password for a facebook (FB) user.
- Now, I want to pass these credentials(via POST,GET or any other way...whatever) to FB to validate the user and if validated, save the user session.
- I read articles on oAuth and understood the idea. However, in that you need to create an APP on FB first and then you can use the APP Id and validate FB user. I do not want to create any APP on FB. I have a username and password and just want to pass it to FB some how and validate the user.

Let me know if this is possible? I work on C#.net/VS2008. However, if it is not possible in .net then please advise if it is possible in any other language/technology.

Thanks and regards,
AG

Comment: _“I do not want to create any APP on FB. ”_ – If you want to operate on the FB platform, then _you do_. If you don’t want to, then you don’t want to work on the platform. Please accept this very basic rule – and don’t try and search for “workarounds”, that would make the user violate FB terms, where there’s absolutely no workarounds necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A user is not allowed per the policy to share its username and password, so what you are proposing is therefor also not allowed, and hence not made possible.

Comment: I agree on that part, but what if user agrees to share the credentials? Not sure on the policy, but I believe, I can try this with my own FB user credentials? correct me here if I'm wrong. In any case, the question is: is it technically possible?

Comment: I believed my comment covered both of those - it is not allowed, and not possible.